# How can I compare two columns with a range on excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vba

How can I compare two columns on excel? considering that I want to compare several rows, for example: between A1-A10 compare with B1-B-10 values

[image]

Comment: After comparing what you want to do?

Comment: Highlight the differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use row differences.

```
Sub SelectDiffRws()
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, rng2 As Range, c As Range

    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rws, 2))
    Set rng2 = Rng.RowDifferences(Range("A2"))

    Columns("A:B").Interior.Color = xlNone

    For Each c In rng2.Cells
        Range(Cells(c.Row, 1), Cells(c.Row, 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Next c

End Sub
```

See here for example
http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Column%20Differences

See here for clip
https://youtu.be/Fcq4rgigu3w

Shareable link to [sample workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByXxMRXssekcSVdWbmNJZ1BTTDQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you this has been useful!